# How is it possible to have two functions with the same names and signatures in the same class?

Tags: kotlin

I am creating Kotlin Class `A1` having two functions with name as `show()` How is it possible to have two functions with the same names and signatures in the same class?

```
    class A1 {
    companion object {
        fun show() {
            println("in A companion")
        }
    }


    fun show() {
        println("in A")
    }
}


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    A1.show()
    A1().show()

}
```

Comment: They _don't_ exist in the same class. One is a member of `A1` and the other is a member of `A1`'s companion object.

Comment: Things in companion object is inside a singleton class (they aren't static), if you annotate that with `@JvmStatic`, then there will be a platform clash for two methods having same signature.

Answer (score 1):

As someone mentioned already in the comments, the one is in the companion object of a class the other one is a class' member.

In Java the first one is translated to `A1.Compantion.show()`, the latter is translated to `(new A1()).show()`.

I don't see any problem here.